# Graph out of incidence matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph-theory

What I need is exactly contrary of ;

```
I = incidence(G).
```

Here I have already an incidence matrix `I`, is there any way to get `G`, which is a graph including Nodes and Edges?

Comment: In principle it should be as I can see so far. You could look for a way to get the adjacency matrix from the incidence matrix. What have you tried so far? Edit: or "collect" source and target node for each edge.

Comment: No, I wanted to know if there is a direct way, like a matlab method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find a Matlab method but the following method I developed is quite straight forward:

```
% Define your test graph
s = [1 1 1 2 3 3];
t = [2 3 4 3 4 5];
G = graph(s,t);
I = incidence(G);

% Find the source nodes from incidence matrix
[s2,~] = find( I == -1 )

% Find the target nodes from incidence matrix
[t2,~] = find( I == 1 )

% Generate graph from source and target nodes
G2 = graph( s2, t2 );
figure;
subplot(211);
plot( G );
subplot(212);
plot( G2 );

% Check
I2 = incidence(G2);

assert( isequal(I, I2), 'Did not generate same incidence matrices' );
```

So all the work is done with `find` and the info:

> I = incidence(G) returns the sparse incidence matrix for graph G. If s
>   and t are the node IDs of the source and target nodes of the jth edge
>   in G, then I(s,j) = -1 and I(t,j) = 1. That is, each column of I
>   indicates the source and target nodes for a single edge in G.

Comment: It returns the exact thing I want, than you for your kind help.

Comment: @HamidrezaMirtaheri: nice to hear. Would be great if you voted up my answer then and accept it, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers